# reading the exit value of a defunct process

Tags: linux, zombie-process

I have a dead process that is now in the defunct state which means that its parent process has not read its exit value. (and it is not going to read it)

I know that the exit value is stored somewhere in the kernel for the parent process to read but, is there a way for me to read that value if I am not the parent process ?

Ideally, I would be able to do this from a shell or an abritrary C/python/your-favorite-language program.

[edit]: This is not a question on how to reap the child or kill it. I do not care if it uses up a slot in the process table. I just want to know what its exit value is. i.e., I would like to read task_struct->exit_code in the kernel.

Mathieu

Comment: I think that `init` takes over as parent of all zombies... Not sure though.

Comment: No, it takes over only once the parent is dead. This is not my case: the parent is still running but I _know_ that it will not read the exit value

Comment: Well in solaris it's a trivial matter of using `preap`, don't know about Linux, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Attempting to call `waitpid()` for a process that is not one of the calling process's children will result in `ECHILD`. You will need to kill the parent process, causing the child to reparent to `init`, which will subsequently reap it.

Comment: Note that I am not looking into how to real the child. I do not care. I just want to look at the damn exit value.

Comment: Doing that would require kernel support; no user process has direct access to it except incidentally, e.g. `strace`.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might be able to do is to send the parent `SIGCHLD`, which tells it that a child has died. If the program is of any quality, it will reap the process.

```
kill -s SIGCHLD parentpid
```